# "Seen by" Feature in posts

Tags: hooks

Do you guess how would be a good practice to achieve a "seen by" feature in every post?
I mean, simply add which users have seen a post.

I'm not sure how to add a hook for that. Neither if I would have some cookie issue.

Comment: Do you mean something like post views

Comment: I mean which users have seen the post, as in Facebook groups

Comment: Something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158230/31545). Your question is very unclear and is in danger of being closed as such

Comment: I know my question is pretty vague, but it isn't unclear. I want to simply add a "seen by" which users have seen the post in every post. Why is it unclear?

Comment: So, the link I have provided in my previous comment is what you need

Comment: It is closed. I don't want only to show how many views the post has. I need to show which users have seen the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this recently in a custom plugin
The basic idea was this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'create_view_entry' ) );
```

---

```
    function create_view_entry()
    {  
    $uid = get_current_user_id();

    if (  $uid != 0 && is_single() )
        $wpdb->insert( $this->tableName, array( 'uid' => $uid, 'pid' => $post->ID, 'date' => current_time( 'mysql' ) ) );
    }
```

This uses a custom database table like this:

```
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, uid INT NOT NULL, pid INT NOT NULL, date DATETIME not null
```

Apologies the code is kinda of vague, it was a very particular solution but this should get you started.
My solution included additional post-type and category conditions in the create_entry function
And create a shortcode to query the database and get user's information

Comment: Thanks, it could work. Is there a reason to add the hook in the footer?

Comment: Because the problem is suppose you're a viewing them from the archive view.

Comment: Added is_single() to conditional,
Could also test with `$post->post == 'single'`

Comment: That would work for single views. I wonder how could I count a view from the archive view as I scroll down. But, that would be more difficult. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely more difficult, not sure why you would want to because that's not actually a "view" in the WP sense.
The best way to do that would be to setup a plugin with a PHP script that accepts a POST to create that DB entry or modify some usermeta. Then use js to test whether or not the user has scrolled past that point. Then make an ajax post to your plugin.